# Jquery select current data

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to select a first row of Bootstrap-datepicker. For some reason, it's always selected a previous month not the current month.

For example: When I click a next month, it shows me a previous data from last month. But I want to show data from current month.

Here's my code: jsfiddle.net/cxtzk6sj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that click event happens before datepicker renders new month. Datepicker itself subsribes to click event on next and prev buttons and your event handler is executed before their.

Very simple solution is to get dates in the next "tick" which you can achieve with setTimeout with zero timeout:

```
$("input").datepicker().on('changeMonth', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".datepicker-days tbody > tr:first-of-type").each(function () {
            $("#result").append("<p>" + $(this).context.innerText + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

Also it's better to use API for month change: "changeMonth" event in your case.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cxtzk6sj/2/

Comment: Thank you for replying so promptly. I have one more question. Is it possible to select class? I need something like this ... if ($(this).attr('class') == "old day") ... inside my each.

Comment: Can you explain better, not sure I understand what you want to select.

Comment: I want to count days of last month. Check it please: http://jsfiddle.net/cxtzk6sj/3/. A November 2015 will return 7, December will return 2.

Comment: Omg :) You're so pro :) I got it in a very very complicated way. http://jsfiddle.net/cxtzk6sj/5/ Thx you so much